# Is there a program what will let me draw a graph and then output its adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph

I do this task manually for lots of graphs. Do you know if there is such a program ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Matlab provides the following function:
A = adjacency(G)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.adjacency.html

Comment: constructing edge list is already exhausting. I am looking for drawing graphs with mouse first, then program will output its adjacency matrix. If there is such a program